# Firestore security rule that only allows empty documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm basically trying to use a firestore collection as a an email list. Anyone can create a document that has their email as the id and nothing more. The tricky part is the "and nothing more" bit. When no data is provided in the request, `request.resource` is `undefined` which you can't check for in security rules to my knowledge. Is this possible? Or is it necessary to have something like one mandatory field for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having empty documents regularly leads to issues down the line. Why not require a single marker field, and validate that in rules?

```
request.resource.data.keys.hasOnly("marker")
```

Comment: No reason other than it felt unnecessary. But if a marker field works and also helps prevent issues then I'm grateful for having that peace of mind now. Though I'm curious to know why exactly that leads to issues?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others looking to make an email list in firestore, this is the full rule I ended up using:

```
match /email-list/{email} {
  allow get: if true;
  allow list: if false;
  allow create: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["marker"]) 
    && request.resource.data.marker == true
}
```